# What is the transform of δ(5t)?

Tags: transfer-function, fourier

So my question is here: How to transform the function $\delta(5t)$?

I know that this function when is transformed on Fourier it will be $1$, but the $\delta(5t)$ is going to be and this $1$ or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about the [scaling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Time_scaling) of the Fourier transform. Under proper conditions, with $a\neq 0$, when the hat $\widehat{\cdot}$ denotes the Fourier transform:
$$\widehat{\delta(at)}=\widehat{\left(\frac{\delta(t)}{|a|}\right)} = \frac{1}{|a|}\widehat{\delta(t)} $$

Comment: I don't know if it's the original answer or the edit, but that formula  displayed isn't right. I think the left hand side should have a frequency variable and it shouldn't be an equals sign.

Comment: Well spotted. Would you be more ok wit this version (avoiding the frequency variable)?

Comment: Yup that works.